# R Shiny // Excel function "freeze pane"

Tags: r, shiny

I have a "head space" with some selectInput widgets in my shiny app. Beneath there are some charts that depend on these filters. Is there a way to freeze the upper part of my shiny app (the one with all filters), so that I can scroll down and see the different charts while having my filters on top?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Take a look at the Shiny Superzip Example and its use of the `absolutePanel`. Perhaps you could use this to hold all of your widgets and position it somewhere on the page? Otherwise, you'll need to make use of CSS I believe.

Comment: You could try `hr()` as fixed horizontal rule to separate two elements in your ui.r script. Look at the HTML Builder Functions of the shiny package. I also like the Application layout guide for shiny at http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html. This might help.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Bootstrap's Affix](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_affix.asp) method. There are many good tutorials out there. Used in Shiny, it could look like:

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Bootstrap Affix in Shiny"),

  mainPanel(
    div('data-spy'="affix", 'data-offset-top'="100",
      wellPanel(
        selectInput("pick", label = "Choose One", choices = c("A", "B", "C"))
      )  
    ),
    plotOutput("sampleplot", height = "700px"),
    h1("Some text"),
    h1("Some text"),
    h1("Some text"),
    h1("Some text"),
    h1("Some text"),
    h1("Some text"),
    h1("Some text"),
    h1("Some text")
  )
)
)
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$sampleplot <- renderPlot({

    df <- data.frame(a = c(1,4,8), b = c(9,10,20))

    ggplot(df, aes(x = a, y = b)) +
      geom_point()

  })
})
```

**Style CSS file in "www" directory of app**

```
.affix {
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;

}

.affix-top {
  width: 100%;
}
```